# QUERY function not including text cells along with number cells in result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm currently trying to copy a list using the `QUERY` function in [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets).

The problem im now facing is that words / letters are not included in the search.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnRb6.png)
[image]

Im using the function: `"=QUERY(E2:F5;)"` but don't get the words included.

Is there any way to include these words by using the formula above as guide?

Comment: What version of [tag:excel] has a native QUERY function? Sounds more like [tag:googlesheets].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets), use Format, Number, Plain Text on your source range of E2:F5 and your original formula will work.

```
=QUERY(E2:F5)
```

From [Docs Editor Help - QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority data types are considered null values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I kinda feel stupid now but thankfully its working now. =)

Comment: No worries; we all have these moments, unfortunately usually under a deadline.